# Detect empty input arg in bash script

Tags: bash

I have a script that has a given number of input variables.
I would like to detect if all of the variables have been given and quit otherwise.
For example lets say the script has 10 input args but only 6 are given.
Then I would like to quit.
I tried

```
arg1=$1
arg2=$2
...
arg10=$10
for i in $(eval echo {$1..$10}); do
   echo "$i"
   if [[ -z "$i" ]]; then
       echo 'wrong number of args'
       exit 2
   fi
done
```

The echo inside the loop (`echo "$i$"`) prints out but the loop always exits. So I have some basic flaw.

Comment: `if [ "$#" -ne 10 ]; then echo 'Wrong number of args' fi`

Comment: For some reason this doesnt work. It always exits whether or not I have the right number of args.